# CPU for Static File Serving

Tags: nginx, cpu-usage

Let's think we have 10 concurrent users per second on the Nginx server which serves only static files: html, css, js.

This is not CPU CPU-intensive operation, but still, Nginx will consume some CPU for configuration file logic. Each user will request multiple static files for example x.html will need 10-20 other static files (js, CSS, images) to serve.

In this case, which type of CPU is better, high-frequency higher single-core performance e.g. Xeon E-2314 or more core lower frequency CPU e.g. Intel Xeon Silver 4208?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: No. If I would need computation like a backend app Node.js, PHP etc., then I would prefer high frequency over more low frequency core, but I don't know whether it is the same for static file serving too. Or if you are using Microsoft Word average modern CPU is enough and any multiple-core or high frequency is overkill.

Comment: a 386 could still serve requests for the internet on static html files. serving static files don't require a strong cpu, it requires a fast storage and a good caching and a reliable internet connection

Comment: What happens to concurrent users? If there are 10 concurrent users per second, and if one HTML page has 20 static files, it means around 200 requests per second. A 386 will still be fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some tests for 500rps-1000rps on a server for just static file serving.

The Server had a 1Gbps port. And basically, the response time was ok until I reached 1Gbps.

I had two CPU limits on my VM. And the CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz. CPUs never got over 40% (I watched CPU load while sending traffic to the server). Rather network was the limiting factor.

So my conclusion is any new multicore average speed (2Ghz) CPU is enough for this purpose. No need for high-end high frequency (higher single-core performance) CPUs.

I did only an HTML file test (with size of 10-40KB), I did not do tests with image files which will be larger in size.